# BIRT - Unable to display data from database

Tags: charts, eclipse-plugin, birt

I'm trying to create a simple report with BIRT (BIRT Designer Release Build: 4.6.0) by connecting to an instance of SQL Server Azure. The data is visible as expected in 'preview' but once I click 'Finish' the data that appears in the chart is the same as the data that is visible when 'Inherit from Container' is selected. I've made a database connection and created a 'Data Set' which is visible in the drop-down selection.

Screenshots of what is happening, below.
[image: This is the sample data when 'Inherit from Container' is selected]

[image: This is the data I'd like to see in the report chart]

[image: This is the data that is visible in the chart even after selecting 'Use Data from']

I don't see any errors in the error log. Somehow, even after selecting 'Use Data from', the correct data from database is not showing up in the chart.

Any leads to solve this issue would be really helpful ! TIA

Comment: 1.Consider recheking on whether the columns that are considered for Series , present in Inherit' are available in DataSource

Comment: When I click the 'Inherit Data from Container' radio button, the drop down box that says 'Inherit Columns and Groups' is greyed out and unclickable.

Comment: This bug discussion( a decade old) has some similar lookout as yours . Esp. read comment 17 . [link](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=159519) . Hope you get some pointers .